# How can I use/override PackageProperties in System.IO.Packaging?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, packaging

I know that if you do the following call:

```
Package package = Package.Open(fileName);
```

a `ZipPackage` is actually returned since the Package class is abstract.  The package class has a property of type `PackageProperties`, which I would like to use. The problem is that the extending class must implement the `PackageProperties` class and `ZipPackage` apparently does not. `PackageProperties` is a read only property on `ZipPackage` and contains all null values.  I cannot extend `ZipPackage` because it is sealed.

So short of writing my own implementation of the `Package` class, is there any way to actually use the `PackageProperties` class and set values on it?

Info On packaging was found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms569886.aspx

Comment: Note: `Package.PackageProperties` property is implemented within `Package` (and NOT abstract). However, the `PackageProperties` _type_ is abstract. Can't you do a: `pkg.PackageProperties.Title = "title";`?

Comment: You are correct about the Package.PackageProperties being implemented but ZipPackage does not actually initialize any of PackageProperties' properties so they are always null.  Trying to set those individual properties does not work either as they are read-only as well.  I am trying to accomplish exactly what you posted there; something along the lines of pkg.PackageProperties.Identifier = "myvalue".

Comment: There are three ways I saw to accomplish my goal: If the ZipPackage class was not sealed I could derive from that and write my own implemenation of PackageProperties. If the PackageProperties property was not read only I could again use my own PackageProperties implemenation. If the PackageProperties' properties were not read-only I could just set them. Alas, none of these is the case so I'm not sure if using that property is possible

Comment: I don't think it'd matter if `ZipPackage` was sealed, because it's not implementing `Package.PackageProperties`, nor is `Package.PackageProperties` a virtual member. Also, `PackageProperties' properties` are, by definition abstract props with getters AND SETTERS. ...?

Comment: I apologize, you were correct.  I swear I'm not crazy. At one point I tried package.PackageProperties.Identifier = "blah" and it cried at runtime about setting a read-only property.  I can't seem to reproduce that now.  Thanks for the help.